# createing a multi dimensional vector of any size

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional histogram using multi-dimentional vectors and I don't know the dimension size ahead of time.  Any ideas on how to do this in c++?

Mustafa

Comment: "I don't know the dimension size ahead of time" - do you mean you don't know it when you write your code, or do you mean that it could *change* at runtime after it's instantiated?

Comment: Did you have a look at [Boost Multidimensional Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own class.  For starters, you'll probably want
something along the lines of:

```
class MultiDimVector
{
    std::vector<int> myDims;
    std::vector<double> myData;
public:
    MultiDimVector( std::vector<int> dims )
        : myDims( dims )
        , myData( std::accumulate( 
            dims.begin(), dims.end(), 1.0, std::multiplies<int>() )
    {
    }
};
```

For indexing, you'll have to take an `std::vector<int>` as the
index, and calculate it yourself.  Basically something along the
lines of:

```
int MultiDimVector::calculateIndex(
    std::vector<int> const& indexes ) const
{
    int results = 0;
    assert( indexes.size() == myDims.size() );
    for ( int i = 0; i != indexes.size(); ++ i ) {
        assert( indexes[i] < myDims[i] );
        results = myDims[i] * results + indexes[i];
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<yourType> >
```

(or maybe if you use a framework you can search it's documentation for a better integrated array replacement ;) )

Comment: How does that solve his problem.  It's an error prone and poorly performing substitute for a 2 dimensional vector; it doesn't support more than 2 dimensions, and it doesn't enforce the requirement that each row have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<int>> mutli_dim_vector_name(num_rows, (vector<int>(num_cols, default_value)));
```

// You can use this format to further nest to the dimensions you want.